# Is it possible to attach existing remote event reciver to newly added document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I am aware that I can attach remote event receiver in SharePoint Online existing document libraries using the **AppInstalled** event SP Add-in.

But, I would like to know the possibilities that when I create new document library in the host web, the event receiver should get automatically attached to it.

It is possible?

I thought of creating event receiver on Content Type, but it seems that it is not possible to attach event receiver on Content Type in SPO.

Answer (score 4):

My normal approach for this would be to add a `ListAdded` remote event receiver to the host web in the `AppInstalled` event.

Now any time a new list is added in the host web your `ListAdded` remote event receiver will be called, and then you can attach your list event receivers as needed.